# How to load an ontology in MarkLogic

Tags: sparql, marklogic

is there a way to load an Ontology in `rdf/xml` or `rdf` format in markLogic ruleset database?

In the [markLogic Documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/inferencing),
it says that to use its own ontology, it must be loaded using the interface on the "`localhost:8001` page" and this ontology must be written in a specific MarkLogic language and have the `.rules` extension.

My question now is: is it possible to use the `rdf/xml` format instead of this MarkLogic format language.

Comment: are you talking about Marklogic itself? If so, it's impossible that you couldn't find this in the docs: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/loading#id_81259 - also, using Google (or the like) with "Marklogic + RDF" returns those links in the top 5: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=MarkLogic+rdf&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 - otherwise, what's the difference with what you call the "ruleset database"? Is this some special store?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 2):

An Ontology is usually expressed in triples, which can be loaded into MarkLogic like any other set of triples. You can import it with MLCP using `-input_file_type rdf`, which supports a few file extensions, including `.ttl`, `.rdf`, and `.owl` if I am not mistaken.

The rules files are exclusively used for Inferencing.

HTH!

Comment: Yes, but my goal is to use the .rdf file as the inference ruleset.

Comment: @Nicco how is an RDF triple converted to a rule? I don't get this point? I mean, RDF can be a fact like `:Bob :knows :Alice`, so how should this be converted to a rule? Or any other RDF triple.

Comment: Yeah, I think it would not be straight-forward to convert this to rules, at least automatically. Also, MarkLogic inferencing happens at query-time, so I think I would not recommend capturing your entire ontology in such rules if not necessary. It could impact performance and resources negatively a lot.

Comment: If you ingest the ontology among the other triples, you can use them in SPARQL directly, without inferencing.

Comment: @UninformedUser the ontology follow the RDFS rules.  In my case the ontology that i need to update is in xml/rdf version. The firsts rows  are these :                             
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY schema "http://schema.org/" >
    <!ENTITY org "http://www.w3.org/ns/org#" >
    <!ENTITY dct "http://purl.org/dc/terms/" >

Comment: @Nicco I'm still not sure what you're asking. RDF is made of triples, Marklogic supports loading RDF data, also RDf/XML - I already showed you the link to the docs. What I don't get is what you mean by the rules. RDF triples aren't rules or can you give an example?